# How does this push button work?

Tags: hardware, button, hacking

I'm on a quest for wireless coffee.

I've succesfully hacked my Nespresso with a NodeMCU that will now let me wirelessly make a coffee. That is, when the machine is already on.  I need to figure out a way to turn it on programatically also, but the button for turning on is different.

After opening up my Nespresso Lattisima+ (model EN520) I found this push button - a kind of button that I don't know.

[image]

How do I find out how it works (i.e. which pins to solder my relay onto in order to switch it on programmatically) without killing myself?

I see a F5 and SW1 next to some pins, but on the back of the printboard I can see that there are pins "hidden", meaning big white block as well.

Thx for helping me stay alive and curious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bär (Baer without the umlaut) is now a brand of Johnson Electric. Check their website:

http://www.johnsonelectric.com/en/features/energy-saving-push-button-switches-for-coffee-machines

Seems these "Tippmatic" switches have some timer built-in.

Comment: Searching for [Tippmatic 3620] turns up more information. See page 77-78 of http://www.contact-evolution.ch/files/burgess-switch-catalogs.pdf for pinout.

Comment: thanks guys - I tried searching for stuff on the pushbutton, but nothing came up - did you guys just know this or is there a logic to finding out?

Comment: You proably searched for BAR instead of BÄR. The umlaut is significant. I then googled "bär switch" ("baer switch" is the same) and got a catalogue of Johnson Electric.